# ValueError: Length of feature_names, 177 does not match number of features, 6

Tags: python-3.x

ValueError: Length of feature_names, 177 does not match number of features, 6

```
dt = rf.estimators_[0]
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(dt, out_file=dot_data, feature_names=X)
(graph, ) = graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Comment: What is X? As the error suggests dt and X are not of same size.

Comment: HI, welcome to SO. Please elaborate a bit on your problem, what are you trying to achieve?. Just providing a piece of code + error isn't always self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the value of feature_names=None, as feature_names is an optional parameter

> feature_names : list of strings, optional (default=None)
>   Names of each of the features.

I think you get the error because the number of features represented by the decision tree and the shape of X doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

The variable X, should have the name of all the columns you have.

In my case, the problem happened because i was onehotencoding the x_train values. to get the names after encoding, 
`transfomer.get_feature_names()` or get the names after any transformations on the input data.

Answer (score 0):

## Export the final model to a Graphviz representation

```py
dot_data = export_graphviz(dt_clf, feature_names=X.columns, filled=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).